# Determine the value of the expression $\frac {5}{\sin^2A} + \frac{7}{\cos^2B}$ if $\cos A = \frac{-2}{3}$ and $\sin B=\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Determine the value of the expression $\frac {5}{\sin^2A} + \frac{7}{\cos^2B}$ if $\cos A = \frac{-2}{3}$ and $\sin B=\frac{3}{4}$.

I applied $$\cos^2B\;=\;1-\sin^2B,$$
and $$\tan^2A\;=\;\frac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}.$$ But I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Your first step was the way you have to do it. You need no $\tan$ , just do the same for $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Using this [trigononometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity)

$$ \cos^{2}\theta+\sin^{2}\theta =1 $$
we get that

$$ \cos^{2}B = 1-\sin^{2}B $$

similary we can find $\sin^{2}A$, and then we just replace
$$   \frac{5}{1-\cos^{2}A} + \frac{7}{1-\sin^{2}B}=\frac{5}{1-\left(\frac {-2}{3}\right)^{2}} + \frac{7}{1-\left(\frac {3}{4}\right)^{2}} $$

there you go...

Comment: Thank you very much